# ssh authentication works, but git doesn't

Tags: ssh, git, cygwin, authentication

I am using cygwin on Windows 10.

When using `ssh user@server.com` ssh correctly loads my `id_rsa`, asks me for the passphrase and then authenticates me on the server.

However, when I try to `git push ssh://user@server.com/~/repo.git`, I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Doesn't git use the ssh mechanism and should therefore successfully authenticate me as well?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a wrong path to your repository. I would guess that it is:

```
git push ssh://user@server.com/repo.git
```

But you should verify that (if you have shell access) with

```
ssh user@server.com ls -l ~/repo.git
```

or

```
ssh user@server.com ls -l repo.git
```

The other possibility is that you have read-only access to that repository.